# How do I include empty strings into the array with the Excel VBA Split function?

Tags: excel, vba, split

I am currently struggling with the split function in VBA Excel. My code looks as following:

```
Dim split_sText() As String
split_sText() = Split(txtString, "|")
```

The textstring to be split looks like this:

```
|ABC|
|DEF|
|
|
|
|
|XYZ|
|UVW|
|123|
```

As you can see there are a few lines with no strings between the delimter `|` which will not be placed into the array.
Is there a possibility to include those "empty strings" into the array?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: As you have pointed out. The string actually looks like this:

```
|ABC||DEF||||||XYZ||UVW||123|
```

This string is only an example. I get this type of string out of an .pdf-file which is then parsed into an .txt-File. That .txt-file is then saved into a string `txtString` with VBA.

The resulting array I want to have in this example should look like this:

```
[0] ABC
[1] 
[2] DEF
[3] 
[4]
[5] 
[6]
[7] XYZ
[8] 
[9] UVW
[10] 
[11] 123
```

Comment: How did you build such a 'string'? Is it extracted (somehow) from a range? Is the pipe simbol only a way to show us how the rows exist? Is it in a cell?

Comment: Good questions @FaneDuru. Also, something like `Split("ABC|DEF||XYZ", "|")` results in an array including an empty value.

Comment: @DXR, can you also include the wanted resulting array with that particular string?

Comment: But, in case of the string looking as you show us after the editing, the required 'empty strings' exists in the obtained array. If your string will be put in a `x` String variable, then after splitting, the next line will prove it: `Debug.Print Join(Split(x, "|"), ","), UBound(Split(x, "|"))`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I hope I was able to explain better now. Please have a look at my edit.

Comment: You could remove the first and last delimiter before doing the Split.

Comment: @ Brian M Stafford. Yes, but @T.M's suggestion does that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question asked:

It is not only possible, it is automatically there already.

Perhaps the question itself is a wrong question?

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understood your question, the `Split` function does exactly what you want. Even more, creating two empty array elements at the begining at of the end.

```
Dim x as String, arr As Variant
  x = "|ABC||DEF||||||XYZ||UVW||123|"
  arr = Split(x, "|")
  'Debug.Print Replace(x, vbCrLf & "|" & vbCrLf, vbCrLf & "|" & "|" & vbCrLf)
  Debug.Print Join(arr, ","), UBound(arr)
  For Each El In arr
    Debug.Print "-" & El & "-"
  Next
  'You probably need to clean the array from its first and last elements (which are not between the pipe characters).
  'Is this assumption correct?
```

Comment: If the last comment in your answer happens to be the issue, then maybe: `Split(Mid(x, 2, Len(x) - 2), "|")`

Comment: @JvdV: Yes, it could be a way. If all the time the pipe character will exist at the beginning and at the end. It maybe would not be wrong to firstly check that...

Comment: ... or `arr = Filter(Split("#" & x & "#", "|"), "#", False)`

Comment: That's even better, but I still don't get what the problem is OP is experiencing in the first place =)

Comment: @T.M.: Yes, more interesting variant... :)

Comment: @JvdV The OP provided what the array needs to look like (even though the issue doesn't match the question title).

Comment: @BrianMStafford, I considered that but since OP mentioned: `" As you can see there are a few lines with no strings between the delimter | which will not be placed into the array."`  I doubt that it would be that simple.